# Lock item when approval starts

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I am making a Custom List that would route for an approval when the user wants to. When an item is routed for approval, I want the item to be locked for editing. How can I achieve that?

I am only making use of SPD 2013. No Visual Studio. SPD2013 is the only thing I must need since our administrator restricts us from utilizing Visual Studio.

Thanls

Comment: If my answer below helped please mark as Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an Impersonation Step at the top of your workflow. This will allow you to take the Current Item, remove all of the current permission levels, and then add back the permissions you desire. Such as adding Read or Restricted Read back on it to lock it from being modified (Contribute).

The Impersonation Step is located in the ribbon. See my image.

[image]

Comment: Thanls, I would look into using list permissions. I had one job where I could only do OOTB solutions, so nothing custom at all. So I used workflows to jump items from list to list, then set list permissions so only certain people could edit / approve on each list. Probably not the most practical solution, but I had fun making it.

Comment: Also, here is some additional information that will help. You will want to first use the Remove List Item Permissions action. Then, use the Add List Item Permissions action to add the permissions back onto the Current Item.

Comment: Thanks @MAllen22842 for this answer. I tried this but with no luck. I used javascript to modify my new, edit and display aspx. But thank you so much. This is still a nice idea though.

Comment: @Ching29 JavaScript is client-side code. Are you using it as a form of "security through obscurity" or to hit the client-side object model (CSOM) to modify permissions? If it is the first, then you are not truly securing those items. If it is the latter then you should be fine.

Comment: I am just doing it to refrain other end user to modify some fields @MAllen22842 and to make some fields readonly.