# How to lock a document in SharePoint Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, item-level-permissions

I've created an app (add-in) in Visual Studio for SharePoint 2013 with a workflow.
The workflow works fine, but when the workflow is running; the document can be updated, deleted,...

How can I lock that document when the workflow starts and unlock the document when it ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to break the permissions from the item and at the end I reset the permissions again.

I did this with a REST request:

1. `/ListItemAllFields/breakroleinheritance(false)`
2. `/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=1 , roledefid=2)`
3. `/resetroleinheritance`

Answer (score 1):

You need to break permissions of the item to achieve your requirement.

**Step 1 :**

When item is triggered for approval process, add impersonation step in your workflow and provide read permissions to all accept approvers (if required)

**Step 2 :**

When your item completes approval process(approved or rejected), provide back the previous permissions to the current item

Hope this solves your issue. Below are some reference links :

[Lock item when approval starts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76130/lock-item-when-approval-starts)

[How do I stop users changing a document going through approval workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/how-do-i-stop-users-changing-a-document-going-through-approval-workflow)